# Simulating clicking a key not working

Tags: javascript, keydown

**I try to simulate WASD for movement on a smartphone.** When i click the button on a smartphone it fires that button but never stops.

How can i tell the program to stop when releasing the button? Is there something like keyup needed or has anybody a better idea?

```
function fireKey(el, key) {
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        var eventObj = document.createEventObject();
        eventObj.keyCode = key;
        el.fireEvent("onkeydown", eventObj);   
    } else if (document.createEvent) {
        var eventObj = document.createEvent("Events");
        eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
        eventObj.which = key;
        eventObj.keyCode = key;
        el.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
}
```

This triggers the buttons:

```
            <paper-button  data-key="LEFT" on-down="handleButton">
                <iron-icon data-key="LEFT" icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-left" style="color: white;"></iron-icon>
            </paper-button>
            <paper-button  data-key="RIGHT" on-down="handleButton">
                <iron-icon data-key="RIGHT" icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-right" style="color: white;"></iron-icon>
            </paper-button> <br/>

            <paper-button data-key="DOWN" on-down="handleButton">
                <iron-icon data-key="DOWN" icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-down" style="color: white;"></iron-icon>
            </paper-button>
```

[It's from this example.](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-17-turn-your-phone-into-a-motion-controller-with-polymer/)

Comment: Have you tried adding an onkeyup event when the button is released?

Comment: what event are you using to trigger `fireKey()`?

Comment: You never tell it to stop. Try with 'keyPress' event instead. Just replace 'onkeydown' and 'keydown' above with 'onkeypress' and 'keypress'.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut onkeyup could work but i don't know how to code it. I've edited the buttons on top.

Comment: @allnodcoms it doesn't react anymore with keydown and onkeydown.

Comment: @Julian - my bad. From the documentation **Webkit-based browsers (Google Chrome and Safari, for example) do not fire keypress events on the arrow keys**

Comment: @allnodcoms I'm not sure, I'm on Chrome (55) and I get events for arrows: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/mPgoYJ

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain how your HTML needs to be changed because you didn't include information about how your on-down attribute is hooked to your event handler - it seems like this must be some sort of Javascript framework.

The problem, though, is clearly that you have an event that tells your key to be *pressed*, but you don't have one telling the key to be *released* again, so once you've pressed the button once your browser will basically just think that key is pressed down forever.

A solution would look something like this, though again I couldn't test this:

```
function pressKey(el, key) {
    fireKeyEvent(el, key, "keydown");
}

function releaseKey(el, key) {
    fireKeyEvent(el, key, "keyup"
}

function fireKeyEvent(el, key, eventName) {
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        var eventObj = document.createEventObject();
        eventObj.keyCode = key;
        el.fireEvent("on" + eventName, eventObj);   
    } else if (document.createEvent) {
        var eventObj = document.createEvent("Events");
        eventObj.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        eventObj.which = key;
        eventObj.keyCode = key;
        el.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
}

<paper-button  data-key="LEFT" on-down="pressKey" on-up="releaseKey">
    <iron-icon data-key="LEFT" icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-left" style="color: white;"></iron-icon>
</paper-button>
<!-- ... -->
```

So this assumes that your framework supports an on-up attribute that works the same way as on-down. It would trigger a keydown event when the button is pressed, and a keyup event when the button is released again.